# Layout weight with two ListViews

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I want two set Listviews vertically.
I want them to be 40% and 60% length of vertical screen respectively.

Here is the code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_weight="0.4" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp">
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="0.6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

     <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/listEvents"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But this doesn't work.
The first ListView takes all the screen.

I have also tried removing the LinearLayout that embeds the two ListViews, but it didn't work either.
I also tried with android:layout_height="wrap_content" in both Listviews and didn't work.

If I rotate screen to landscape and after back to port again, it works.
It fails the first instance creation.

Any idea on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This layout will work:

```
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     >
     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/lvwView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="0.4"
     />
     <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/elvEvents"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Just **don't inherit** from `ListActivity` or `ListFragment`!